# Android requirements GLIBC

Tags: android, linux

Does any body know where to find the **GLIBC2.7** for **RHEL5** without this the Android emulator wont start.It gives a message as **GLIBC 2.7** or above is required.

I tried searching the net and none is avaible

Comment: Fiddling with the C library on an enterprise distribution is black magic. Perhaps just run the latest Fedora in a VM?

Comment: Agreed, you don't want to try to change the glibc in your distro. You might get away with running your emulator in a chroot jail where you've got glibc 2.7+, but it's likely easier to use a different system or VM.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. After spending all day trying to get around it, I finally had the thought to install the Windows version of the SDK on my Windows 7 machine and it works like a champ! I know, that's probably considered heresy to some of you guys, but if they can't make it work on CentOS, then what do you expect?

Not only have I gotten the emulator to work, but I've been able to install the .apk on my phone and it works just like the emulator. So, if you can't beat 'em, join 'em.

Comment: You should probably try ubuntu .I got this working on Ubuntu.But people whats the use of specifying the requirements when there are no options..